# ClassNotFoundException for com.facebook.FacebookActivity

Tags: android, facebook, apache-flex, facebook-android-sdk

I want to integrate Facebook's Android SDK (v4.11) into my Android app and my final apk is compiled via Flash Builder because of flex-sdk dependencies.

Unfortunately, I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` for `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` in my stack-trace when my app tries to create the concerned Activity that initialises Facebook.

I have included the classes.jar in the Native Extension for my Android source code and dependencies. On decompiling the classes.dex file in the final .apk using dexdump from Android SDK build-tools via the following command:

```
./dexdump classes.dex | grep 'Class descriptor'
```

I am able to see

```
Class descriptor  : 'Lcom/facebook/FacebookActivity;'
```

which indicates that FacebookActivity.class *has* been packaged and compiled in the .apk.

I also bundled all Facebook-sdk resources along with my project's resources in the res folder in my native extension (this is the first time I had to include third-party resources with my own in a native extension).

My `onCreate()` code which initialises the Facebook-SDK:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); //throws the ClassNotFoundException
 AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```

My `AndroidManisfest.xml` entries as per Facebook-documentation:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                  android:configChanges=
                      "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

I am using version 4.12 now with no change in results.

Also, here is my build.gradle entry: (Although that does not effect flex packaging much, as I have to use ziptree on the facebook sdk JAR).

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+"
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        /**
         * newer cardview has compatibility issues with android-sdk default styles.
        **/
        compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
            force = true
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's my custom gradle task which I am using to package the compiled dependencies and source classes:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
        //external libariries - their jars containing compiled classes obtained from the .idea -> libraries -> <libName>.xml file
        from (zipTree("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar"))
        from (zipTree("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar"))
        from ("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/res")
        from (zipTree("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/customtabs/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar"))
        from ("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/customtabs/23.4.0/res")
        from (zipTree("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk/4.12.1/jars/classes.jar"))
//        from ("build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk/4.12.0/res")
        from(zipTree("/$USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-android/1.4.0/cc174c559b5177982887bf6e1b76003aebad9516/bolts-android-1.4.0.jar"))
        from(zipTree("/$USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-applinks/1.4.0/8ad21bf21784dacce5f2043afb97218cc377e835/bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar"))
        from(zipTree("/$USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-tasks/1.4.0/d85884acf6810a3bbbecb587f239005cbc846dc4/bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar"))
        //soucre code
        from ('build/intermediates/classes/release/') {
            exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
            exclude '**/R$*.class'
            exclude '**/R.class'
        }
        //jar name and destination directory
        archiveName = "src_and_dependencies.jar"
        destinationDir = file("/$USER_HOME/Ane/build/ane/Android-ARM")
    }

    //before running fatJar task, the old jar should be deleted and the project should be re-built
    fatJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

Comment: What is that second activity?android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"

Comment: It is a custom chrome tab activity to handle the use case when Google Chrome and Facebook apps are both not present on the device.

Comment: Are you getting "functions over 65k limit" when you package as a normal android app (Not with flash) ? Does flash builder uses gradle tasks ?

Comment: @S.D. I will have to check that, but the jar I supply to the flash builder is built using a custom gradle task which I just updated in my question above.

Answer (score 3):

Add the dependency into your `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.0'
}
```

or you can use the .jar, this is the way for exporting:

go to `Project` > `Properties` > `Java Build Path` > `Order and Export` and click on jar's checkbox.

Comment: I have updated my question now to include my dependencies. Also, I am using Android Studio - and so am unable to find the Order and Export navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your proguard file

```
-keep class com.facebook.FacebookActivity { 
    public *; 
}
```

Comment: I am not having any problems while building the apk from Android Studio. I get this exception while exporting my compiled source code and dependencies in a jar via a manual gradle task (which is working for other dependencies than facebook). Does proguard play a role in manual gradle tasks as well?

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided it appears that you have used the package name 'com.facebook' for your custom application. However, this might conflict with the 'com.facebook' package used by the facebook sdk.

Please change your package name and try.

Comment: The manifest entries provided above are specific to and as per the Facebook SDK [guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android). These aren't the names of my custom activities, I have used my own namespace for them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are having duplicate Facebook libraries, one path through Facebook SDK jar file in libs folder and the other through the gradle Facebook reprository cache.

You can skip the `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'` altogether and use `compile project(':libs:facebook')` instead.

Comment: Yes, but this was another probable answer distinct from the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is, you will need to move the following to onresume instead of onCreate() :

```
FacebookSdk. sdkinitialize     
(getApplicationContext();
Apparentlyogger.activateApp(this);
```

It solved my problem before.

**EDIT**

try this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this,"{your facebook app id}");
}
```

And of course do not forget:

```
  private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Canceled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        String title = "error";
        String alertMessage = error.getMessage();
        showResult(title, alertMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        if (result.getPostId() != null) {
            String title ="success";
            String id = result.getPostId();
            String alertMessage ="successfully_posted_post, id";
            showResult(title, alertMessage);
        }
    }

    private void showResult(String title, String alertMessage) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                .show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Since this is a ClassDefNotFound exception, I am not sure how shifting the code to onResume would help. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

It must have exceded the infamous 64k method limit, you need to enable your app for multidex. Here is how you do it. https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Wouldn't this give me an error at build time though? I am able to finish building my .apk file at the moment.

Comment: Had this problem as well, over the 64k limit. It does not limit your building, but there is only place to register so many methods / classes. So at runtime it goes looking for stuff, and can't find them. Hello crash.

Comment: yes kaushik, it doesn't give error at build time, only at run time, that too when the method is not indexed within 64k.